# Prolog Expert System (Animal Identification System)

Tags: prolog

Hey I have this piece of code here that identifies an animal on sound, color and type(which is vertebrate and invertebrate). The type is further broken down into sections such as nerve cord, skeleton, etc. This photo captures all the info. If the user says the animal does not have an internal skeleton how do I make it in such a way that it automatically selects external since there is no other option? It wont let me paste the code for some reason, keeps giving me an error so I put it on google drive.

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdIE3.png

Code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ehQfYdfTR0Txx9mG5A7XZRhdZ5M1V0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Um, are you using an unusual Prolog system or have you written a lot of code without testing it? Your first line appears to have three mistakes in it; `-` needs to be `:-`, and `dynamic thing` needs to be `dynamic(thing)` and `known3` needs to be `known/3` .  All your facts throw errors in SWI Prolog. The way you've shaped them, even if they weren't errors there's no easy way to use them. Asking the user is broken in several ways, you can't get information from the user. Nothing looks right, but then why have you written so much of it?

Answer (score 0):

One way (using SWI Prolog) is:

```
ask_skeleton(Skel) :-
    write("Internal skeleton? [yes/no]"),
    read(X),
    (   (X=yes, Skel=internal)
    ;   (dif(X, yes), Skel=external)).
```

Which behaves:

```
?- ask_skeleton(Result).
Internal skeleton? [yes/no]
yes
Result = internal


?- ask_skeleton(Result).
Internal skeleton? [yes/no]
no
Result = external


?- ask_skeleton(Result)
Internal skeleton? [yes/no]
asdfasdfasdf
Result = external
```